# vscode prettier setting ploblem

Tags: visual-studio-code, prettier

I'm using prettier + esling in my vscode.

I can't find some settings. I don't know what to descrive so here's some example code.

```
void set()
{
    ::n = 10;
}

void set() {
    ::n = 10;
} // I prefer this way
```

and when i'm using namespace in c++

```
namespace example
{
int n;
void set()
{
    doodle::n = 20;
}
} // namespace example

namespace example
 {
    int n;
    void set()
    {
        doodle::n = 20;
    }
} // namespace example
```

can you help me with this settings? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow.

Prettier is an "opinionated" formatter, which means that it does not provide many customization settings -- it just formats code the way it thinks code *should* look.

You may wish to uninstall or disable Prettier, and simply use the formatting settings natively present in VSCode, accessible from `preferences`.

Or, you can search the VSCode Marketplace for a C++ formatter with more customization options: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/

Comment: I understand. Thank you for your kind answer!

Comment: @N0Name No problem!  If this answered your question, you can click the ✔ check mark and the ▲ upvote arrow on the left side.  This will indicate to other folks that question was answered and/or helpful.  (Of course if it didn't answer your question, then don't).  Anway, good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Press ctrl+P (for MAC use cmd+P) and search for settings.json, and add this line:

```
"editor.formatOnSave": true
```

after that, whenever you press ctrl+S for saving, it will format your code.

Comment: I asked about prettier code style... but Thank you for your answer!